# How can I make two pageLoad functions for other divs?

Tags: jquery, css, updatepanel

I have a little problem with my jQuery code... I have two updatePanels on my page and I want to make two different pageLoad functions for two different updatePanels(divs). Is this even possible?

My code:

```
function pageLoad() {

        $('.imageset-nowosci').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);

        $('.previousbtn-nowosci').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imageset-nowosci').animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500, function () {
                $(".imageset-promocje").css("opacity", "1");
                __doPostBack($('.previousbtn-nowosci').attr('name'), '');
            });
        });

        $('.nextbtn-nowosci').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imageset-nowosci').animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500, function () {
                __doPostBack($('.nextbtn-nowosci').attr('name'), '');
            });
        });

        $('.imageset-promocje').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);

        $('.previousbtn-promocje').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imageset-promocje').animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500, function () {
                __doPostBack($('.previousbtn-promocje').attr('name'), '');
            });
        });

        $('.nextbtn-promocje').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imageset-promocje').animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 500, function () {
                __doPostBack($('.nextbtn-promocje').attr('name'), '');
            });
        });
    };
```

The problem is - when I click nexbtn-nowosci it's changing the opacity for imageset-promocje also. I want to split this function on a halves, that my nowosci btns don't work on imageset-promocje... Any ideas?